# Fair Algorithm to choose K item From N items

Tags: algorithms

we have a website that users pay money for their posts to get featured for 24 hours or 48 hours, we've considered showing three items at the home page, at this time we choose three items randomly but it's not fair and we are looking for a fair algorithm to show items.

we have  following items:

- K: number of items we want to choose ( in our case =3)
- N: number of featured posts
- E: minutes remain to expire
- S: number of an item has been shown

A simple solution is calculating `(E + S) / N` for all items, the sort them Ascending and finally choose K item in each run. but I think it mays be better.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Reservoir sampling is pretty standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling . The general Wikipedia page for uniform random selection is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample .

Comment: @PatrickStevens thank you for your attention, but I'm not looking for simple random choice, it's not fair because my list getting updated each minute.